# What's the font family of the page title on MobileSafari?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, safari, mobile-safari

The webpage title on MobileSafari looks carven，host to make this effect?And what's the font family and font size of the title?

Thank you very much!
[image: safari]

Comment: Have you tried e.g. [WhatTheFont](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open any iOS project in Xcode.
2. Launch MobileSafari in the simulator and visit google.
3. In Xcode, choose Product > Attach to Process > MobileSafari.
4. Choose Product > Debug > Pause.
5. In the debug console, type `po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`.

Note that this only works on the simulator.  On the device, you can only attach to apps that you have installed using Xcode.

Doing all that gives you a printout of Mobile Safari's view hierarchy.  Searching through it, I find this `UILabel`:

```
   |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1096e800; frame = (0 0; 308 16); text = 'Google'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1096e8c0>>
```

The address of the `UILabel` object will be different each time we do this.

Anyway, we can print that label's font like this:

```
(lldb) po [0x1096e800 font]
$2 = 0x0bb88110 <UICFFont: 0xbb88110> font-family: ".Helvetica NeueUI"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 13px
```

We can print its text color:

```
(lldb) po [0x1096e800 textColor]
$13 = 0x1096eb50 UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.173 0.212 0.259 0.9
```

We can also print its shadow color:

```
(lldb) po [0x1096e800 shadowColor]
$4 = 0x1096eb70 UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 0.43
```

Printing the shadow offset is harder, because it is a `CGSize` structure, not a built-in type.  The debugger doesn't know about `CGSize` because MobileSafari doesn't include debug information.  We have to give the debugger a definition.  This hideous command works:

```
(lldb) expr -o -- typedef struct { float x; float y; } CGSize; (id)[NSValue valueWithCGSize:(CGSize)[(id)0x1096e800 shadowOffset]]
$11 = 0x08063e60 NSSize: {0, 1}
```

Comment: holy informative batman! nicely done rob. just as effective (maybe...for my uses), nowhere near as technical: iphone view source bookmarklet http://snoopy.allmarkedup.com/

Comment: The toolbar showing the title, URL field, and search field is not part of the page source, so a view source bookmarklet will not help.

Comment: lol. never noticed that...so let me take back the second part of that statement, but i still meant the first. nicely in-depth

Comment: Thank U very much!I got it like this:label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.000000];
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.173 green:0.212 blue:0.259 alpha:0.9];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.43];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

Answer (score 2):

It's the system's default font, Helvetica-Neue. In UIKit, you'd get it with `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:...]` or `[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:...]`. The "carve" effect is a simple white drop shadow. It's achieved with the `shadowColor` and `shadowOffset` properties of `UILabel`.